# Linear Transformation, if $T(x) \neq 0$ for some $x \in V_1$, prove that $Tx \neq 0 \iff x \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I don't know if it's true, but it seems to be, altought I cannot prove it yet.

I'm trying to find a way of write any other vector as a sum of $\textbf{x}$ with another vector (I don't know if it will work because I don't know if $T\textbf{y} = 0, \textbf{y} \neq \textbf{x}$) and multiplication by scallar, but don't know how.

I think it's pretty simple but I can't figure out.

Comment: If $x=0$, then $Tx=0$. But the converse is not true.

Comment: Even if $Tx \neq 0$ for some $x$ ?

Comment: The equivalence $Tx \neq 0 \Leftrightarrow x \neq 0$ is true if $T$ is injective.

Comment: Even if $Tx≠0$ for some $x$, may exist $y$ such that $Ty = 0$ or not. Depends on $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false.  All you need for a counterexample is a nonzero linear transformation which is not injective.  For instance, the one whose matrix rel the standard basis for $\Bbb R^3$ is $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$.